# Specify multiple rdf:types in a SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have a SPARQL query like this

```
PREFIX prefix: <http://example.org/ns#>
SELECT *
WHERE 
{
    ?x rdf:type ?type .
}
```

Suppose now I want to specify the type of `?type` as being either `prefix:type1` or `prefix:type2`; how should this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Much faster than the `FILTER IN` function is the use of `BINDINGS`.  I would highly recommend using something along the lines of the following query rather than the `FILTER(?type IN (wo:Kingdon, wo:Phylum)`.

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?x rdf:type ?type } BINDINGS ?type {(prefix:type1) (prefix:type2)}
```

Using `BINDINGS` allows the SPARQL engine to limit results as it is being processed rather than returning all results before filtering them. This makes returning the results much faster.

Comment: It's not BINDINGS anymore;  it's VALUES.  This approach is nicer than the one using UNION, though, and nicer than using FILTER( ?type IN …).

Answer (score 15):

You could use `UNION` e.g.

```
PREFIX prefix: <http://example.org/ns#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    { ?x a prefix:type1 } UNION { ?x a prefix:type2 }
}
```

Note the use of `a` which is a SPARQL keyword that may be used in the predicate position and corresponds to the RDF type URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type`

There are other ways to do this such as using `FILTER` clauses with various expressions:

- Series of `?type = prefix:type1` combined with the conditional or operator `||`
- `?type IN (prefix:type1, prefix:type2)`

Or you could use a `VALUES` clause to specify the options for `?type`

These may be better if your query is more complex and you don't want to duplicate much of the query onto both sides of the `UNION` or have more that two possibilites to consider.

Comment: "the ?type in" appears interesting, but its not working, I'm surely making an error on syntax, is it right? SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?x rdf:type ?type 
    ?type in (wo:Kingdom, wo:Phylum)
}

Comment: These are expressions that can be used in a `FILTER` clause so it would be `FILTER(?type IN (wo:Kingdon, wo:Phylum))`

Answer (score 5):

As Joshua mentioned, the accepted answer is no longer accurate in SPARQL 1.1.

In SPARQL 1.1, the [VALUES](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) keyword can be used but the syntax looks more complicated for use-cases like this one. However, you can write that in compact form as well:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  VALUES ?type { prefix:Type1 prefix:Type2 }
  ?x rdf:type ?type
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using the FILTER syntax, like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX prefix: <http://example.org/ns#>

SELECT ?s ?p ?o ?type
WHERE {
   ?s a ?type .
   ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER(?type IN (prefix:Type1, prefix:Type2))
}
```

Please note that I cannot guarantee efficiency, as I do not know if the the filtering will apply after all the results will be returned or not.